# Sort version in tableau

Tags: sorting, tableau-api

I'm new in tableau, and I'm trying to build a report.

I have a field of versions,

```
e.g: 36.0.0.8667, 39.0.0.8267, 42.0.0.9639, 42.0.0.10249.
```

I need to find the two newest versions (meaning the highest value in the first part, from that group the highest value in the second part etc...) and make a comparison between the two of them and the average for all versions (between dates).

Does anyone have any idea how can I find the two newest versions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

tablelau for dashboard right?
you just need filter that can get 2 biggest valu from database
example like this.
the output will be 2 biggest value

```
select max(p.total),a.tot from product p,(select max(`total`) as tot from `product`) as a where total < (select max(`total`) from `product`);
```

Comment: Thank you, but select MAX doesn't work with that type of content (for the versions...)

Comment: in the filter column?